# Sorting lines of a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort each line in a 2D array alphabetically. 
I'm reading in from a file, and I can do that just fine:

```
int n_char = 0;
int charCount = 0, wordCount = 0, lineCount = 0;
int wordsPerLine[100];

char buffer;
char words[50][75];

wordsPerLine[0] = 0;
while( (n_char = read(fileDescriptor, &buffer, sizeof(char))) != 0) {


        if (buffer == '\n' || buffer == ' ') {

            words[wordCount][charCount] = '\0';
            charCount = 0;
            wordCount++;
            wordsPerLine[lineCount] += 1;
            if (buffer == '\n') {
                lineCount++;
                wordsPerLine[lineCount] = 0;
            }

        } else {

            words[wordCount][charCount++] = buffer;


        }
    }
```

All of the words and lines read in just fine, but now I'm having a problem sorting the lines. I know how many words are in each line, and I know how many lines there are in the array, so right now I'm keeping a running count off all the words, and noting the first word of a new line. My question is how do I go about sorting all of the lines?

So far all I have is this:

```
int runningSize = 0;
for(i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", runningSize);
    printf("\t%s\n", words[runningSize]);
    runningSize += wordsPerLine[i];
}
```

If that's unclear, here's an example:

Input:

```
hello world
goodbye world
elephants are really cool
```

Expected Output:

```
elephants are really cool
goodbye world
hello world
```

Comment: Your question should be: How do I sort multiple lines of strings .... You are sorting the lines not the words of each line .. correct me if I am wrong?

2- do you care about your sorting to be stable or not?

Comment: Yes you are correct - I definitely worded that wrong. And it does not have to be stable, I just want the lines sorted haha.

Comment: Alright that makes it much clearer, David has a good solution for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel. You can use one of the included sorted algorithms to accomplish this for you. The following example show how to sort strings using `qsort`. It can easily be adapted to your situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sortstrarr(void *array, unsigned n);
static int cmpr(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(void) {
    char line[1024];
    char *line_array[1024];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf ("Enter one string per line (ctrl+d when done)\n");

    while(fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) {

        if (i < 1024)
            line_array[i++] = strdup(line);
        else
            break;
    }

    printf ("\npassing strings to sortstrarr (using qsort)\n\n");

    sortstrarr (line_array, i);

    while (j < i)
        printf ("%s", line_array[j++]);

    return 0;
}

static int cmpr (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

void sortstrarr (void *array, unsigned n) {
    qsort (array, n, sizeof(char *), cmpr);
}
```

output

```
Enter one string per line (ctrl+d when done)
this is my string
alother one
maybe one more
been there
done that

passing strings to sortstrarr (using qsort)

alother one
been there
done that
maybe one more
this is my string
```

Comment: You need to notice that this sorting is unstable. I wonder how can u make it stable & still efficient

Comment: How so @AK_? When you say unstable, do you mean it crashes or the sort order gets messed up?

Comment: Not at all David, I mean the sorting algorithm you're using (qsort) is not *stable* - I think the example stated here is very clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability


**Edit**: The asker has stated that it is not required to be stable so you're good :)

Comment: Oh!, sorry I chose that one then, you can use any sort you like, bubblesort, heapsort, etc., I just had a qsort example in one of my files that was ready to go.

Comment: That's alright, I think qsort does a great job at this scenario (much more efficient than bubble-sort for example) -- one more question: Why did you declare `strcmp` as static? could you explain please?

Comment: In this case there is no need for the static designation. In the file it was coped from it was shared by a couple of sources.